# A/C still blows when unit is off.

Tags: hvac

Our A/C is turned off but we still get cold air coming out of the vent diffusers. This is from our downstairs unit. Is that a problem?

Comment: A question that has to be asked: On the thermostat is a switch that says "Fan: On-Off-Auto". It's not in the On position, is it?

Comment: Is the outside compressor unit running as well as the interior fan? Nothing should run when turned off. Sounds like the thermostat may be bad or a contactor/relay is stuck in the unit.